# Two wireless NIC on RaspberryPi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, network-adapter, raspberry-pi

I want to be able to use two wireless network adapters on my RaspberryPi running wheezy (Debian).One card is to be used to connect to the network and I want the other to run in the monitor mode.

Two cards I'm using are identical: Dynamode WL-700N-RXS 150Mbps Nano 802.11n Wireless USB Adapter Dongle

Being a windows user this is getting a little out of my comfort zone and I would like to ask you for help with setting this up.

So far I tried using two dongles on my laptop under Network Security Toolkit and straight after the boot everything worked as I hoped for.
Things started to get complicated for me when I tried to do it under Wheezy on RaspberryPi

- First it didn't recognize any of the NIC under iwconfig but in lsusb
  i could see them but it looked like the both adapters have same MAC!
- Google told me how to change the MAC under linux and now under iwconfig i can see wlan0 but no trace of wlan1

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nfnetlink_log           8620  0 
nfnetlink               4929  1 nfnetlink_log
nfsd                   67106  0 
ipv6                  291230  30 
spidev                  5588  0 
arc4                    1387  2 
rt2800usb              12481  0 
rt2800lib              48137  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt               1553  1 rt2800lib
rt2x00usb              11851  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              43907  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
mac80211              251866  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              180452  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
spi_bcm2708             4905  0 
i2c_bcm2708             3818  0
```

ip link show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:6d:7c:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:54:38:a7:fa:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:6d:7c:ed  
          inet addr:192.168.1.143  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe6d:7ced/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:41614 (40.6 KiB)  TX bytes:21456 (20.9 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:54:38:a7:fa:5d  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# wlan0
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
# change mac
pre-up macchanger -m 30:54:38:A7:FA:5D wlan0

# wlan1
auto wlan1
```

Comment: Disconnect wlan1, connect again and provide `dmesg | tail -90` output.

Comment: "Two cards I'm using are identical" - it is not correct, according your `lsusb` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`september` is right that they are not identical `148f:5370` and `148f:7601` identifies usb vendor and usb product (e.g. you can see Linux supported usb devices on [this link](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices/USB), although it is not a complete list). So that they are from the same vendor but not the same usb devices anyway.

On the above link and `lsusb` says that `148f:5370` uses `RT5370` chipset. [Debian's wiki page](http://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb) says that chipset uses `rt2800usb` driver. The `lsmod` output shows that your Debian has `rt2800usb`, that's why you don't have any problem with that device and can use it as `wlan0`.

However, I couldn't find chipset of `148f:7601`. However, http://support.dynamode.com/wireless-devices/wireless-usb/wl-700n-rxs/ says that it uses `Realtek 8188SU` chipset. Again referring the [Debian's wikipage](http://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x):

> **Debian 7.0 "Wheezy"**
>   This release supports Realtek RTL8188CE, RTL8188CUS, RTL8188DE, **RTL8188SU**, RTL8191SE, RTL8191SU, RTL8192CE, RTL8192CU, RTL8192DE, RTL8192E, RTL8192SE, RTL8192SU and RTL8192U-based devices.
>
> **1)** Add a "non-free" component to /etc/apt/sources.list, for example:
>
> deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
>
> **2)** Update the list of available packages and install the [firmware-realtek](http://packages.debian.org/firmware-realtek) package:
>    sudo apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
>
> RTL8192U-based devices only: firmware is required to be manually supplied:
>
> sudo apt-get install unzip && exit
>
> wget ftp://ftp.dlink.com/Wireless/dwa130_revC/Drivers/dwa130_revC_drivers_linux_006.zip
>
> unzip dwa130_revC_drivers_linux_006.zip $ su
>
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/firmware/RTL8192U
>
> sudoo cp rtl8192u_linux_2.6.0006.1031.2008/firmware/RTL8192U/* /usr/local/lib/firmware/RTL8192U
>
> **3)** Connect the device to your system.
>
> **4)** [Configure](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse) your wireless interface as appropriate.